# Java generic method to get value of type by using switch on type

Tags: java, generics, methods, switch-statement, typeof

I want to have something like this below (example how I would do this in C#), to get typed value from SQLiteDB:

```
private T GetValueFromDB<T>(String colName) {
    object returnValue = null;

    switch (typeof(T)) {
        case Boolean:
            returnValue = dbData.getInt(colName) == 1;
            break;

        case Int32:
            returnValue = dbData.getInt(colName);
            break;

        case Int64:
            returnValue = dbData.getLong(colName);
            break;

        case String:
            returnValue = dbData.getString(colName);
            break;
    }
    return (T)returnValue;
}
```

Is there a possibility (with switch case or if else) to implement it in Java?

Comment: There is no way to get the actual class of a generic type parameter at runtime. Had the same problem some time ago.

Comment: I don't get the meaning of this function. How would you use this function? And in Java, the definition of the method should be something like: private <T> T FOO(String colName)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you already know the type when calling the method, you could do something like this:

```
private T GetValueFromDB<T>(String colName, Class<T> returnType) {

    if(returnType.equals(Boolean.class)) {
        return (T)(dbData.getInt(colName) == 1);
    } else if(returnType.equals(Int32.class)) {
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar when programming in Android and I have error - Cannotcast from boolean to T. 
public <T> T get (String key, Class<T> returnType) {
   if (!sharedPreferences.contains(key))
      return null;
   else {
      if(returnType.equals(Boolean.class)) {
        return (T) (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false));

Comment: I am getting the same error. Cannot cast from int to T. Does this method actually work? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Ok, the problem was with autoboxing. I was trying to cast an int to T. If I save the int in an Integer variable and then cast it to T, it works fine. Oh Java!

Comment: what about when `returnType` is a generic class?

Answer (score 6):

Java uses **type erasure** so it is impossible to determine type of *T* at runtime.

Comment: ...so if you want to implement it, you will have to add another parameter to your function (Class<T> clazz) and use it to compare the actual class.

Answer (score 1):

I have made inteface switch, maybe it can be useful for someone :

```
new ISwitch(pagerCtrl.getPager().getFragmentByID(fragment_id))

      .addCase(new ISwitch.CaseListener<Type1>() {
        @Override
        public void Case(Type1 instance) {

        }
    }).addCase(new ISwitch.CaseListener<Type2>() {
        @Override
        public void Case(Type2 instance) {

        }
    }).addDefault(new ISwitch.DefaultListener() {
        @Override
        public void Default() {

        }
    }).build();



public class ISwitch {

    public interface CaseListener<T> {
        void Case(T instance);
    }

    public interface DefaultListener {
        void Default();
    }

    Object value;
    LinkedList<CaseListener<?>> col = new LinkedList<>();
    DefaultListener defaultListener;


    public ISwitch(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void build() {

        boolean wasNotifiedMinimumOnce = false;
            for (CaseListener<?> c : col) {

                try {
                    CaseListener<Object> l = (CaseListener<Object>) c;
                    l.Case(value);
                    wasNotifiedMinimumOnce = true;
                    break;
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                }
            }

        if ( !wasNotifiedMinimumOnce ) {
            if ( defaultListener != null ) {
                defaultListener.Default();
            }
        }
    }



    public ISwitch addCase(CaseListener<?> caseListener) {

        col.add(caseListener);
        return this;
    }

    public ISwitch addDefault(DefaultListener defaultListener) {
        this.defaultListener = defaultListener;
        return this;
    }


}
```

The small drawback of implementation is that we cant make check **instanceof**, that why i catch it on cast. For me its not big deal, but it can be performance issue on java server code executed XXXXXX times each seconds.